# Has anyone made a graph of the swagger definition for the square API?

Tags: square-connect

The API is difficult to understand. I was just wondering if such a graph has already been made? Or is there perhaps a good explanation of how all the parts fit together?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a graph? There isn't a ton of overlap between different endpoints, so I'm not sure if such a graph would be very interesting. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/mcf-rocha/swagger-graph. For example, there's an order_id as "foreign key" in the transaction data structure, but there's no direct link in the doc to order. It would be nice to have all those connected. As far as I could tell there's no documentation like a data dictionary or anything about how the flow works, so I think a graph would be helpful.

Comment: You can find our Swagger/ Open API specification here: https://github.com/square/connect-api-specification/blob/master/api.json, you are welcome to try to visialize it anyway you want!